# なってきています and なっています

Tags: grammar, meaning

What´s the difference between なってきています  and  なっています?

For example:
お隣の人達、大丈夫?　ヤバくなってきているよ。

Would it´s meaning change significantly if it´s changed into: 
お隣の人達、大丈夫?　ヤバくなっているよ。

Comment: なってきています = it is starting to become ... / it has started to become ... なっています = it is becoming ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful if gave specific examples because what seems like a simple question touches some quite complicated grammar, which I will try to cover briefly:

First you need to understand the nature of ~ている. There are several questions covering this quite well so I won't repeat them but will try to summarise:

なる is a "punctual verb", that is to say that when using the ~ている form, the resultative state precludes the continuative state.  In other words if we say:

> この地方は交通が便利になっています。

This usually means:

> In this region the public transport has become convenient. (i.e. "is convenient")

It can also mean "is becoming convenient" but to convey that sense (ie it is in a transition state) additional words, typically adverbs are often used to create the context. eg:

> この地方は交通がだんだん便利になっています。
>
> In this region the public transport is gradually becoming [more and more]convenient.

Second: 〜てくる／〜ていくis used to convey change in position or time. Often these communicate the movement/action of the speaker (「いってきます！」）or movement of something/action with respect to the speaker (「電話がかかってきた」）but they can also be used to convey continuation of a state or "process of change". eg:

> この地方が交通がだんだん便利になってきた。これからは観光客が多くなっていくと思う
>
> In this region public transport gradually became convenient.  Going forwards, I think the number of tourists will be very large.

Comment: I´ve added an example. Reading your explanation, would I be correct in concluding  ~てきています can always be translated into ~ing and with ~ています it depends on the specific verb/context?

Comment: If you want to convey something is "in progress", or in the "continuative state" with a verb like なっている then context is all important: Not entirely sure about your example but I would say やばくなっている implies they are in trouble, ヤバくなってきている indicates they were not in trouble before but they have got into and are still in trouble (which is only a small difference). ている and てくる are separate subjects.  Have a look at the　answers other questions on these areas and this website, recently recommended by Snailplan: http://homepage3.nifty.com/park/aspect.htm

Comment: Thanks for answering(and everyone else too of course). The link looks especially promising.

Answer (score 2):

For example, 暖かくなってきています is "it's getting warm" while 暖かくなっています is "it has become warm" = "it is warm".